# Is it possible to install this program via wine?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I have a program that I would like to install with wine, but I cannot get it to work on wine1.6-dev or regular wine. It gives me a "bad exe" error. The software I am trying to install is located [here](http://www.awesomeminer.com/download.aspx).

I did try installing netframework 4.7, and net framework 4.5 with no luck.

I read somewhere about switching to wine 32bit, but it did not exactly solve my issue.

Below is my error log.

```
laptop@laptop:~/Downloads$ wine msiexec /i AwesomeMiner.msi
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
fixme:msi:ControlEvent_SpawnWaitDialog Doing Nothing
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {5eec90ab-c022-44b2-a5dd-fd716a222a15}, 0x10001123, 0x10019040, 0x10019058
fixme:msi:ITERATE_CreateShortcuts poorly handled shortcut format, advertised shortcut
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {5eec90ab-c022-44b2-a5dd-fd716a222a15}, 0x3c1123, 0x3f1070, 0x3f1088
fixme:service:svcctl_ChangeServiceConfig2W SERVICE_CONFIG_FAILURE_ACTIONS not implemented: period 0 msg L"" cmd L""
err:service:service_send_start_message service L"IntelliBreezeMaintenanceService" failed to start
err:msi:ITERATE_StartService Failed to start service L"IntelliBreezeMaintenanceService" (1053)
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"StartServices" returned 1627
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1627
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
err:rpc:I_RpcGetBuffer no binding
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister 0: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister 0: stub
```

Comment: Wine 1.6? The latest stable is 2.0, I think that you may be using an ancient version.

Comment: Did you try mono? It could be a .net application!

Comment: thanks. updating to the latest 2.0 worked along with mono